# MySQL: records, inserted via phpMyAdmin, do not replicate

Tags: mysql, replication, phpmyadmin

As it says on the topic, for some reason records inserted/ modified via PMA do not get replicated to the slave, If I do exactly the same insert/modification on master via mysql command line, or application, it does get replicated as it should be.

Is it some security feature ? Or something wrong ? I use MySQL 5.5.28 with CentOS 6 mostly.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: It's not a security feature... more likely a case of misconfigured replication.  Are you trying to replicate the entire server's data set (the standard configuration), or did you try to limit it to specific schemas or tables (because that's almost always what causes replication to not behave as expected)?

Answer (score 1):

I do not use phpMyAdmin so maybe i'm out but take a look on a potential autocommit option in the UI... Maybe your PMA's session isn't in autocommit (test with : SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  "autocommit").

Other thing, do you have filtered replication ? (do-replicate, do-ignore...)

Max.

Best regards.